# Question on the definition of sheaves.

Tags: abstract-algebra, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves, quasicoherent-sheaves

When defining a sheaf of $O_X $-modules, or sheaves in general, I have nearly always seen it given as a functor from the category of all the open sets to another category with the usual properties.

However when looking at some specific examples, (e.g here http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9906037v1.pdf)

We seem to define it on some open cover of the space.

Does this define the sheaf everywhere else automatically? Or is there something else going on?
Please can someone try and explain this to me.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous: yes, a sheaf is determined by its restrictions to an arbitrary open covering but no, a sheaf is not determined by giving its sections on the sets of an open covering unless the covering forms a basis of the topology of the space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is enough to define a sheaf on some open cover. It is a fact that it will define the sheaf completely. For example, you can see Corollary I-14 in Eizenbud-Harris "Geometry of schemes". This book has very nice explanation of the issue you are asking about.

Comment: If you don't mind helping me further, in the link I provided what are the global sections? are they just constant polynomials over the field $k$ ?

Comment: @JC574 Which example you are talking about?

Comment: I don't think that it is enough to define a sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on some open cover. In particular $X$ itself is an open cover of $X$. So this would imply that it suffices to know $\mathscr{F}(X)$ to know $\mathscr{F}(U)$ for each open subset $U\subseteq X$. This is clearly wrong.

Comment: Rather, one must define the sheaf on a _basis_ for the topology.

Comment: how does this tie in to the text i linked in the question? Isn't the author there just defining the sections on the standard affine open cover?

Comment: If you have an open cover $\{U_i\}$ s.t. $\mathcal{F}|_{U_i}$ is a sheaf, then there is a unique way of gluing it together. It doesn't mean that the values $\mathcal{F}(U_i)$ define the sheaf. However, if the covering is affine, say $U_i=Spec(R_i)$, then it is enough to define only $A_i:=\mathcal{F}(U_i)$, since this value will define a sheaf $\mathcal{F}|_{U_i}$ on each piece.

Comment: Namely, for any sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $U=Spec(R)$ it is determined by $\mathcal{F}(U)=R$. Indeed, for any principal open set $U_f$ (collection of these sets give a base of topology) one defines $\mathcal{F}(U_f)=R[\frac{1}{f}]$.

Comment: @Sasha: You need to add some words here (quasi-coherent for example).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thanks, Martin! You are right. The gluing part is correct, though. It is just the part that *quasi-coherent* sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ is defined by the values $\mathcal{F}(U_i)$ on affine pieces.

Comment: thanks guys this was v. helpful